# Сохранение идентификаторов из ответа json

Tags: java, json, gson, rest-assured

Есть ответ `json` cо списком идентификаторов:

```
{"products": [
    {"product_id":163},
    {"product_id":145},
    {"product_id":146},
    {"product_id":151},
    {"product_id":161},
    {"product_id":165}]
```

Есть массив в классе, в который я записываю ответ:

```
class ApiData
{
static class Product
{
int product_id;
Product (int product_id) 
{
    this.product_id = product_id;
}
}

class Application
{
    List <Product> products;
    Application (List <Product> products)
    {
        this.products = products;
    }
}
List <Product> products = new ArrayList <> ();
Application Application = new Application (products);
String appObj;
}
```

И есть класс, в котором я в методе получаю ответ `json` и записываю в массив:

```
    class ApiSteps
    {
    void getProd ()
    {
    apiConfig.response = apiConfig.request.post (apiConfig.getProd);
    apiConfig.responseBody = apiConfig.response.getBody ();
    responseBodyAsString = apiConfig.responseBody.asString ();
    apiConfig.jsonPath = apiConfig.response.jsonPath ();
    apiData.Application.products.add (new ApiData.Product (apiConfig.jsonPath.get ("products [0].product.id")));
    apiData.Application.products.add (new ApiData.Product (apiConfig.jsonPath.get ("products [1].product.id")));
    apiData.Application.products.add (new ApiData.Product (apiConfig.jsonPath.get ("products [2].product.id")));
    apiData.Application.products.add (new ApiData.Product (apiConfig.jsonPath.get ("products [3].product.id")));
    apiData.Application.products.add (new ApiData.Product (apiConfig.jsonPath.get ("products [4].product.id")));
    apiData.Application.products.add (new ApiData.Product (apiConfig.jsonPath.get ("products [5].product.id")));
    apiData.appObj = apiConfig.gson.toJson (apiData.Application);
    }
    }
```

Но я записываю по одной строчке, а их количество может быть больше. Как можно получить список всех идентификаторов и записать их в массив разом?

Comment: Использовать цикл for и пробегать по всем объектам из массива `products`

Comment: А как это должно выглядеть в данном случае?

Answer (score 1):

Можно изменить класс `ApiData` следующим образом:

```
public class ApiData {
    private Products[] products;

    //add getters and setters

    public static class Products {
        private Integer product_id;

        //add getters and setters

    }
}
```

Затем, чтобы заполнить этот объект, советую воспользоваться стандартным способом, который предоставляет `rest-assureg`, например:

```
ApiData data = given()
    .when().get(endpoint)
    .then()
    .extract()
    .body()
    .as(ApiData.class);
```

В этом случае все элементы массива `products` будут сохранены в переменной `data`.